# Get SNI sent by the client in netty

Tags: java, netty

How do i get the SNI sent by the client in Netty, I am able to successfully switch the SslContext based on the SNI however for logging purposes I need to extract the SNI sent by the client. Is there a way to do it ? In OpenSSL it is just 1 line to get it from the SSL *. Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the hostname by holding a reference to the `SniHandler` and then call `hostname()` on it once the selection is done. I must admit this is a big "ugly" so I just wrote a PR [1] to improve this by allowing you to intercept the `SniCompletionEvent`. That said its not merged yet so for now you need to use the `SniHandler.hostname()` method.

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/7444

Comment: I tried getting the the channel.pipeline().get(SniHandler.class) but seems to fail. I get null. The SNI handler is already in the pipeline. pipeline.addLast(new SniHandler(mapping));  Am i missing something here.

Comment: You need to store a reference to the handler somewhere as the handler will replace itself with the `SslHandler` when it selects the `SslContext` based on the hostname.